# Create a preg_match filter so only new facebook fan pages without duplicate get added to sql database

Tags: mysql, database, facebook, filter, preg-match

Please help to correct a filter problem. 
Its a facebook fan page like website for users to add and like fanpages for each other.

want to do:
no duplicate Facebook fan page gets added to site database.
filter (http or https) and facebook fan-page link (with or without / ) as same.

```
example 
http://www.facebook.com/Shareitto
https://www.facebook.com/Sharetto
http://www.facebook.com/Sharetto/
They all could be added to the site (this is problem, I want to filter)
Below is the complete code with filter




            if(isset($_POST['add'])){
            if(!preg_match("/\bfacebook.com\b/i", $_POST['url']))
        {$msg = "<div class=\"msg_error\">ERROR: You need to add facebook page!
        </div>";}
            else if($_POST['title'] == ""){$msg = "<div class=\"msg_error\">
        ERROR: Title can't be empty!</div>";}
            else{
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'facebook' (user, facebook, title, cpc)
         VALUES('{$data->id}', '{$protectie['url']}', '{$protectie['title']}',
         '{$protectie['cpc']}' ) ");
            $msg = "<div class=\"msg_success\">Page added with success!</div>";
            }}
            ?>






     If need more, please reply!
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd approach this is to only store the part of the URL after *http://facebook.com/*, so in the case you mentioned only "Sharetto" is stored. This makes lookups a lot easier, as performing REGEX in MySQL is an unnecessary use of resources in this case. When pulling out the data from the database you would then prepend the fanpage name with the Facebook URL.

I would pick out the important part of the URL using a regular expression like this:

```
$url = "http://www.facebook.com/Sharetto/";

$matches = array();
if (preg_match('~^https?://(?:www\.)?facebook.com/(.+)/?$~',$url,$matches)) {
    $fanpageName = $matches[1]; // In this case: "Sharetto"
    // Do lookup in DB for $fanpageName, not $url
}
```

Basically, throw away the Facebook URL completely, and just pick out the important part.